# Boost plus Cloudflare

Tags: performance, caching, files

Can we use [Boost](http://drupal.org/project/boost) together [Cloudflare](http://drupal.org/project/cloudflare)?

I am curious whether using both can be enabled on the site, and whether doing so will actually improve performance.

Comment: I don't think questions about CloudFlare as a service is on-topic on this site, and the way the question is formulated, it's currently as much about CF as about Drupal. I sort of wish the question was on-topic, but I don't think it is.

Comment: Cloud Flare is available as a module on Drupal.org http://drupal.org/project/cloudflare So comparing the two is not a bad idea

Comment: Even though this question might seem off-topic, and you can't really answer it without touching CloudFlare as a service, I think it's a useful question and it's contributing to the knowledge base of the site. I'm not in favour of closing it.

Comment: The first part of the question reminds me of [Gorilla vs. Shark](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/). The last question is probably subjective: It depends from the site.

Comment: I think the rewrite has merit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I currently use Boost and Cloudflare together on a medium sized site, I don't have any current performance figures to show you but there is a substantial improvement in performance and scalability by using the boost module with the cloudflare service. I don't use the cloudflare module itself as it only allows you to submit Spam reports & ban/whitelist IP addresses.

I use the boost module and have then setup my account on cloudflare.com to cache static assets like images etc
Boost on its own does a great job of serving more pages faster. However as my site has a lot of static assets and that is primarily why i use the cloudflare service.

Comment: Thanks for the 2nd para of your answer. So the main difference in cache technology is as follow 

What kind of static content does CloudFlare cache?
CloudFlare caches common static content file extensions, including JavaScript, CSS and images. The full list of what CloudFlare caches can be found here. http://blog.cloudflare.com/cloudflares-free-cdn-and-you

Does CloudFlare cache dynamic content, such as HTML or PHP?
CloudFlare does not currently cache these content types.